# Unknown Command -Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot

```
package de.gdv.sp.configuration;

import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import com.captcha.botdetect.web.servlet.CaptchaServlet;

@Configuration

public class CaptchaConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "captchaServlet")
    public ServletRegistrationBean captchaServlet() {

        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CaptchaServlet(), "/kontakt");
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement BotDetect Captcha  in our Spring MVC/Boot project.When I tried to create servlet with annotations( without web.xml) I always get the following screen:[screenshot of http://localhost:8080/kontakt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3XB1.png)

Moreover when I write the HTML code of this captcha, I get the following result.[Botdetect Captcha does not show picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viWLG.png)

```html
<botDetect:captcha id="exampleCaptcha"/>

<div class="validationDiv">
    <input id="captchaCode" type="text" name="captchaCode"
            value="${basicExample.captchaCode}"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    <span class="correct">${basicExample.captchaCorrect}</span>
    <span class="incorrect">${basicExample.captchaIncorrect}</span>
</div>
```

How can I solve this problem?

[BotDetect Captcha website][3]

Answer (score 1):

You can try either:

1. extend WebApplicationInitializer

   ```
   package de.gdv.sp.configuration;

   import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
   import com.captcha.botdetect.web.servlet.CaptchaServlet;

   @Configuration

   public class CaptchaConfiguration extends WebApplicationInitializer {

       @Bean(name = "captchaServlet")
       public ServletRegistrationBean captchaServlet() {

           return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CaptchaServlet(), "/kontakt");
       }
   }
   ```
2. move your bean definition into a class that extends WebApplicationInitializer.

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class WebXMLReplacement extends WebApplicationInitializer {

       //other configurations

       @Bean(name = "captchaServlet")
       public ServletRegistrationBean captchaServlet() {

           return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CaptchaServlet(), "/kontakt");
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There is Standard way to Register your custom servlet in Spring MVC application. You need to Create Initializer Class by implementing WebApplicationInitializer.

```
    import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;
    import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
    import com.captcha.botdetect.web.servlet.CaptchaServlet;
    public class MyServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
        throws ServletException {
            Dynamic myServlet = servletContext.addServlet("kontakt", CaptchaServlet.class);
            myServlet.addMapping("/kontakt");
        }
    }
```

You could use this approach to register DispatcherServlet
manually.Similarly, you can register listeners and filters by creating a new implementation
of WebApplicationInitializer.